# Optionally passing a struct to a custom function in C#

Tags: c#, struct, null, optional-parameters, custom-function

There are other similar SO posts on this, but I'm struggling to find anything that makes much sense. Still fairly new to C# here...

So, all I want to do is add an optional parameter to a custom function. This param needs to contain two values so I figured a custom struct would work, like this:

```
public struct FooBah {
    public string foo;
    public string bah;

    public FooBah(string foo, string bah) {
        this.foo  = foo;
        this.bah = bah;
    }
}
```

Then to use it in a function call:

```
FooBah foobah = new FooBah("foo", "bah");
CustomFunction(foobah);
```

And for the function itself:

```
private void CustomFunction(FooBah foobah = null) {
    if(foobah != null) {
        // Do something with foobah
    }
}
```

But this errors because:

> A value of type '' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'FooBah'

Any advice please?

Comment: Simplest solution: create an overload of `CustomFunction` that takes no parameter at all. This works regardless of what `FooBah` is and also gives you an opportunity to document the semantics for this case better than you could with a single method (since it's not obvious what omitting the value should mean in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a default state for the struct that you can detect (such as `foo` being null) you can write code like this:

```
static void CustomFunction(FooBah foobah = default)
{
    if (foobah.foo != null)
    {
        // Do something with foobah
    }
}
```

Of course this depends on your usage of `foo`.

Alternatively you can use a `FooBah?` parameter:

```
static void CustomFunction(FooBah? foobah = null)
{
    if (foobah == null)
    {
        // Do something with foobah
    }
}
```

The following calls all work:

```
CustomFunction();
CustomFunction(new FooBah());
CustomFunction(null);

var fooBah = new FooBah();
CustomFunction(fooBah);
```

Note that if you don't want to modify the struct inside the method you can use the `in` modifier:

```
static void CustomFunction(in FooBah? foobah = null)
{
    if (foobah == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Default");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not default");
    }
}
```

Note that when using a nullable value type, you must access the value itself via a `.Value` property, i.e. `foobah.Value.foo` - this is because the type is `Nullable<FooBah>` rather than `FooBah`.

[See here for the Nullable value type documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

[See here for more information](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/) on when you should use `in`.

Finally the most obvious solution is to overload the method with and without a parameter.

Comment: Aha, I think that ? operator is all I needed, thanks! Could you just explain what that does please? I take it it's like a ternary if() in other languages?

Comment: @Ric: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: @Ric See the helpful link that /u/SomeBody posted!

Comment: Perfect, thanks both. So effectively the parameter itself is nullable but the struct isn't, so you can either not pass a struct, or pass a struct that isn't null, and within the function I can just check if the param is null or not to determine if there's a struct to use? If I'm understanding this correctly, that's exactly what I've been looking for :D.

Comment: @Ric: You've got it.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon actually! Currently getting "FooBah? does no contain a definition for 'foo' and no accessible extension method 'foo' accepting a first argument of type 'FooBah?' could be found" errors when trying to read foobah.foo after the != null check...

Comment: @Ric What version of C# are you using? [Try this code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCOW4I)

Comment: Also note that the `in` modifier requires a later version of the C# compiler.

Comment: Unity 2021.3.8f1. Confusingly released August 2022. So presumably a fairly recent C#...

Comment: C# 9 apparently.

Comment: You sure you're not using the `in` modifier?

Comment: My code here with the FooBah usage is obviously simplified, so I've pasted a somewhat redacted copy of the real script here: https://pastebin.com/ZTQCeJpU  . So, line 27 and 30 set the struct up and call PostRequest at line 43, which uses the ? nullifier for param 2. Line 57 is what's then generating the "does not contain a definition" errors.

Comment: Hmm. This works in dotnetfiddle (it errored trying to sign me up to save there), but doesn't feel as tidy as the ? approach... https://pastebin.com/akKrpBQV

Comment: Spoke too soon again. That last pastebin doesn't work in C# 9. Blimey this is frustrating!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know why it's not working in your code, all I can say is that the code I posted works with .NET 4.7.2 or later, which you can see in the DotNetFiddle...

Comment: You can check which version of the language and runtime is being used by adding `#error version` to the code somewhere. It will fail the compile and output an error message including the compiler version and the C# language version being used.

Comment: I've given up - removed all the struct stuff and now just constructing the auth header elsewhere and passing it in as a flat string for injection, rather than passing a struct of the two variables for construction on the fly. To be fair I suppose it's more efficient this way anyway as it's not having to do a Base64 encode every time, but it doesn't feel like a nice way to code it...

Seems structs in C# 9 just aren't very useful though.

Leaving your answer as the accepted, as it does seem to be what works in newer compilers. Thanks for the subsequent discussion too.

Comment: It definitely works with C# 9 (and C# 8) though, but I don't know why it's not working in Unity.

Comment: Actually if you change line 23 of your fiddle to `Console.WriteLine(foobah.foo);` it spits out the same error I see in Unity. If you instead go the `= default` route and add a parameterless constructor to the struct, like in my https://pastebin.com/akKrpBQV version, this works in fiddle but not in Unity - apparently because C# 9 didn't support that. Structs just don't seem useful in C# 9 which is a frustration for me as associative arrays don't appear to be a thing in C# either. I can see me having to create an inordinate number of classes for trivial data blocks moving forwards!

Comment: Oh I see now - you just need to put `foobah.Value.foo` rather than `foobah.foo`. If you read the link given by  /u/SomeBody earlier you will see the documentation. I'll update the answer to include that information.

Comment: Ah amazing, thanks - that does work! Now to decide whether I should re-implement the struct or stick with the efficiency... I need a break!

Answer (score 1):

This could work, but your structure is not nullable, as in it can't be converted to null, hence, you could do it like this to define an optional argument -

```
public struct FooBah {
    public string foo;
    public string bah;

    public FooBah(string foo, string bah) {
        this.foo  = foo;
        this.bah = bah;
    }
}

FooBah foobah = new FooBah("foo", "bah");
CustomFunction(foobah);

private void CustomFunction(CustomFunction? structOptional = null){
//What you want to do with the struct
}
```